# Remove point from hashtag Regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift3, hashtag

I'm using KILabel for my Swift project, in order to transform hashtags to links. My problem is that the regex function that I did is capturing point as well.For example, if a user write #18.3 I would like to capture only #18

I tried some things, in order to cut the hashtag at a point, but without success.

```
regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(#+[\\S\\_]+)?" options:0 error:&error];
```

Do you have any idea about how I could do this ?

Comment: Try `@"#[^\\s.]+"`.  If there can be dots inside, use `@"#[^\\s.]+(?:\\.[^\\s.]+)*"`

Comment: You mention Swift in your question and tags, but your code is clearly Objective-C, so which one are you actually using?

Comment: your solution seems to work ! :) Sorry about that, I code in Swift but the framework is in Objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have matches 1+ `#` chars and then 1 or more any non-whitespace characters.

To stop matching before the first dot, use

```
@"#[^\\s.]+"
```

If there can be dots inside, use

```
@"#[^\\s.]+(?:\\.[^\\s.]+)*"
```

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `[^\s.]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `.`
- `(?:\.[^\s.]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^\s.]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `.`.